# Simulating an API call with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest, api, vue.js

I want to simulate an API calls. I am writing an application in VueJS, and I'm currently retrieving my data from a hardcoded JSON file I created.

For example, from my `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <p>{{ teams.yankees.city }}</p> // Will output "New York"
</template>

<script>
  import teams from './teams.json'

  export default {
    data() {
      return { teams }
    }
  }
</script>
```

From my `teams.json` file:

```
{
  "yankees": [
    { "city": "New York", "established": 1901, "worldSeries": 27 } 
  ]
  ...
}
```

I can as of now successfully retrieve my data from my local JSON file - but how can I instead retrieve data using "function stubs", in a way that will allow me to swap in real restful API calls in the future?

Is there a barebones resource somewhere, that shows how to set up a mock rest service that calls my local JSON file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using json files as your mock data, you don't need anything but a simple http server. Put teams.json file somewhere in your project directory and serve it using http server of your choice, for example this [simple, zero-configuration command-line http server](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server).

Then access your mocked data using [Vue resource](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-resource) plugin:

```
{
  this.$http.get('http://localhost:8080/teams.json').then((response) => {
    // success callback
  }, (response) => {
    // error callback
  });
}
```

I guess you don't want to hardcode urls in your service calls. What I like to do is to have a mapping file where I define resource *names* and map them to concrete paths:

```
{
  teams: 'http://localhost:8080/teams.json'
}
```

This way I can switch between different resource locations without changing my business code.

If you need something more sophisticated you can either build it yourself or check out existing services, for example [mockable.io](https://www.mockable.io/) or [apiary.io](https://apiary.io/).